# Can cards/features be turned off?

Tags: achievements, sky-force-reloaded

Is there a way to turn off or disable the effects of cards?

For example after receiving the "Increase Plane's Speed" card the game always starts your plane one notch faster then the normal. I would like to fly some stages extra slow. You can always take the "Iron Clad" to fly 10% slower but I want to be able fly at the slowest speed available which can be achieved by disabling the "Increase Plane's Speed" card and taking the "Iron Clad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards once obtained cant be deactivated, at least as of update 1.46